# when trying npm install -D live-sever errors occur javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I always face troubles when i do npm install in my system. this time I am following  javascript tutorial so he shows us to use the command `npm install -D live-sever` and  it occurs errors. by the way im using internet behind  proxy.

```
`npm ERR! code E404
 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/live-sever - Not found     
 npm ERR! 404
 npm ERR! 404  'live-sever@*' is not in this registry.
 npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)   
 npm ERR! 404
 npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
 npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name is [`live-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server):

```
npm install -D live-server
```

Comment: after  that I have to use `npm start` command and then  `Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8080` error occurs

Comment: Try a different port. Include `--port=<port num>`, e.g., `live-server --port=8090`